# Match and Replace similar words with a common word

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a vector of unique districts (dist) and a vector (dist_plus) where have some additional value with each district.
My goal is to create the 'result' where similar district name will be replaced by unique district.

```
dist <- c("Bengaluru", "Andaman","South 24 Parganas")
dist_plus <- c("Bengaluru Rural", "Bengaluru Urban", "South Andaman","North Andaman","South 24 Parganas")


result <- c("Bengaluru", "Bengaluru", "Andaman","Andaman","South 24 Parganas")
```

What is the simplest way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: for-loop + `gsub`. Type `?gsub` in R console

Answer (score 2):

```
dist <- c("Bengaluru", "Andaman","South 24 Parganas")
dist_plus <- c("Bengaluru Rural", "Bengaluru Urban", "South Andaman","North Andaman","South 24 Parganas")

library(tidyverse)

# vectorised function to spot matches
f = function(x,y) grepl(x, y)
f = Vectorize(f)

# create a look up table of matches
expand.grid(dist_plus=dist_plus, dist=dist, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  filter(f(dist, dist_plus)) -> look_up

# join dist_plus values with their matches 
data.frame(dist_plus, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  left_join(look_up, by="dist_plus") %>%
  pull(dist)

#[1] "Bengaluru"         "Bengaluru"         "Andaman"           "Andaman"           "South 24 Parganas"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_detect` to compare the similar word:
First, check for the similar word using `str_detect` and if it exists then replace the word from `dist` vector and `loop` over the all elements in `dist_plus`.

```
library(stringr)
c(na.omit(unlist(lapply(dist_plus, function(x) ifelse(str_detect(x, dist),dist,NA)))))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Bengaluru"         "Bengaluru"         "Andaman"           "Andaman"           "South 24 Parganas"
```

Comment: `str_detect` is not a base R function and you'll have to specify which package it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is is the way for you to understand it well. There are many ways. Here is one way by using a `for` loop.

```
# create an empty result with NAs
# if your final result has any NAs it means something probably went wrong
result <- rep(NA, length(dist_plus))

# for each dist_plus check if it contains any of the dist
for (d in 1:length(dist_plus)) {
  # d is an integer and it will span from 1 to how many elements dist_plus has

  # traverse all elements of dist (sapply =~ for ()) and see if 
  # any element appears in your subsetted dist_plus[d]
  incl <- sapply(dist, FUN = function(x, y) grepl(x, y), y = dist_plus[d])

  # find which element is this (dist[incl]) and write it to your result
  result[d] <- dist[incl]
}

[1] "Bengaluru"         "Bengaluru"         "Andaman"           "Andaman"          
[5] "South 24 Parganas"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want.

```
inx <- lapply(dist, function(s) grep(s, dist_plus))

result2 <- character(length(dist_plus))
for(i in seq_along(inx)){
    result2[ inx[[i]] ] <- dist[i]
}
```

In the test below `result` is the vector in the question.

```
identical(result, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for giving so many different way to solve the problem. I have also figured out a solution.

```
library(plyr)

dist <- c("Bengaluru", "Andaman","South 24 Parganas")
dist_plus <- c("Bengaluru Rural", "Bengaluru Urban", "South Andaman","North Andaman","South 24 Parganas")
result <- c("Bengaluru", "Bengaluru", "Andaman","Andaman","South 24 Parganas")

r <- dist_plus

l_ply(dist, function(x){
  r[grepl(x, dist_plus)] <<- x
})

identical(r, result)
#[1] TRUE
```